# How to receive multiple values from a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jsp

A javascript function is being called at the time of page loading which is returning multiple values and i need to receive those values. What should i specify in form or body tag so as to make use of those values in my jsp page?

The code i am using is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Browser()
{
    var myWidth;
    var myHeight;

    if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) { 

    //Non-IE 

    myWidth = window.innerWidth;
    myHeight = window.innerHeight; 

    } else if( document.documentElement && 

    ( document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) { 

    //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode' 

    myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth; 
    myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight; 

    } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) { 

    //IE 4 compatible 

    myWidth = document.body.clientWidth; 
    myHeight = document.body.clientHeight; 

    } 
    return {myWidth:myWidth, myHeight:myHeight};

    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="Browser()">
<form name="hello" action="" method="post" >
<table align="center" border="1">
<tr>
<td>
User Name:
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="user"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Password:
</td>
<td>
<input type="password" name="pwd"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
<td colspan="2">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code function Browser is returning the resolution values and i
had called that function using onload() method. How should i receive those 
values of myWidth and myHeight so as to use them in the same jsp page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can return a object containing all the relevant values:

```
function myFunction() {
    return { val1: 1, val2: 2, val3: 3 };
}
```

usage:

```
var tmp = myFunction();
var val1 = tmp.val1;
var val2 = tmp.val2;
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your commented out return statement is fine:

```
return {myWidth:myWidth, myHeight:myHeight};
```

It can then be used in other javascript like so:

```
var dimension = Browser();
var width = browser.myWidth;
var height = browser.myHeight;
```

You will not have access to these variables on the server (unless you post them) since javascript executes on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Return a JSON object or an array of results.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass all your variables together, using some JSON notation to pass the data

```
document.write('{myWidth:'+myWidth+',myHeight:'+myHeight+'}');
```

Once you have the data, decode the JSON and use your variables.